# Django - The info is showed but still giving error

Tags: python, django

I'm making a CRUD, when i try to add a sell list this is reflected when i check the result but give an error when goes to add.

Here the error code:

```
TypeError at /manage/add_sell_list/

list() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/manage/add_sell_list/
```

Here the models.py section:

```
class Sell_list(models.Model):
    sell_list_key = models.ForeignKey(User)
    #sell_list_key= models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    object_name = models.CharField(max_length= 150)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.object_name
```

Here the views.py section:

```
@login_required(login_url='/loginuser')
def new_sell_list(request):
    return render(request,'new_sell_list_form.html',{
        'action': 'add_sell_list',
        'button': 'Add',
        })

@login_required(login_url='/loginuser')
def add_sell_list(request):
    new_sell_list_name= request.POST["new_sell_list_name"]
    colectr_user = request.user
    to_save_list= Sell_list(
        object_name = new_sell_list_name,
        sell_list_key = colectr_user
        )
    to_save_list.save()
    return list(request, message= "sell list added!")
```

Here the url.py

```
url (r'^manage/new_sell_list/$', 'stock.views.new_sell_list', name='new_sell_list'),
url (r'^manage/add_sell_list/$', 'stock.views.add_sell_list', name='add_sell_list'),
```

the form who adds the register to DB:

```
<form action="/manage/{{ action }}/" method="post"> 
    <input name="new_sell_list_name" value="{{ sell_list_name }}"><br />
    <input type="submit" value="{{ button }}">
</form>
```

This only needs to return to the manage page i created when add the info.

Comment: What is `list`, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved with:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/manage')
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @200OK This stock message doesn't really fit here :^)

Comment: the real problem is, this isn't useful as doesn't tell what the problem was, how this solved it or even where it goes in the source.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help others to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to `return list(request,message='sell list added!')`, you are try to convert the request and message to a list, but, list() takes only 1 argument.

I think you made a mistake while trying to return a list instead of returning a render or redirect to a success page or list page.

Try change it:

```
return list(request, message= "sell list added!")
```

For a return similar to what you did with the method `new_sell_list`

```
return render(request,'successful_list_added.html')
```

Or:

```
return redirect('redirect_url')
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot call another view like this:

```
return list(request, message= "sell list added!")
```

you need to return an HTTPResponse, in this case, HTTPResponseRedirect, like this:

```
return redirect(reverse('list_view_namespace', kwargs={ here kwargs, if any}))
```